# RIGHT JOIN not returning all results

Tags: mysql

I have `posts` table. Each post has `topic_id` field which corresponds to the appropriate `id` field in `topics` table.

I need to sort `topics` by the `date_created` field in `posts` table.

Also, each topic has `forum_id` and I need to show and sort only topics with particular `forum_id`.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
   topics.id, topics.title 
FROM 
   topics RIGHT JOIN posts ON topics.id = posts.topic_id
WHERE 
   topics.forum_id = 1 
ORDER BY 
   posts.date_created DESC
```

However not every topic has posts associated with it. Those that do not have any posts are not returned.

How to fix it?

Comment: You cannot filter left-side table in right join in where clause because by the time filter is applied missing row will be already substituted with null row, and null does not equal any value. Result is inner join. Move the filters concerning `topics` table to ON clause.

Comment: Bring filter back to where - only those applied to outer table need to be stated in ON clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LEFT JOIN instead of RIGHT JOIN

Comment: Same result - only topics with posts are returned and those without are left out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   topics.id, topics.title 
FROM 
   (topics RIGHT JOIN posts ON (topics.id = posts.topic_id))  
WHERE 
   topics.forum_id = 1 
ORDER BY 
   posts.date_created DESC
```

try this

Comment: This but with `LEFT JOIN` solved the problem. Both of you were almost there :).

Comment: How exactly does *"adding a few parentheses"* help solving the problem? This query is exactly equivalent to the OP's original attempt. @Vaibhav Remove the parentheses and you'll see that the LEFT JOIN does the trick, not this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe lost rows because there is no data on posts. Try cast null value with ifnull function like this:

```
SELECT 
   topics.id, topics.title 
FROM 
   topics LEFT JOIN posts ON topics.id = posts.topic_id
WHERE 
   topics.forum_id = 1 
ORDER BY 
   ifnull(posts.date_created, '1900-01-01 00:00:00') DESC
```